# Meus arquivos .jar gerados pelo Eclipse não estão abrindo

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Já fiz tudo o que sei e o que encontrei pela internet para abrir um arquivo .jar, mas nada funciona. Quando dou 2 cliques ele simplesmente não abre, não dá erro, mas também não abre nada. Já tentei executar pelo Prompt de Comando do Windows, aparece o seguinte. "nenhum atributo de manifesto principal em Gym.jar", já abri essa tal pasta no manifesto, fiz alteração mas continua a mesma coisa.

Também testei o arquivo em outro computador, deu no mesmo. Gerei outros arquivos .jar e também não funciona. Gero esses arquivos pelo eclipse. Já havia gerado arquivos .jar a alguns meses atrás e funcionou normal, mas agora não sei mais o que fazer.

Dentro no meu arquivo MANIFEST.MF possui a seguinte informação: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true.

Comment: Você fez `java -jar seuarquivo.jar` ?

Comment: Já, aparece isso.
"nenhum atributo de manifesto principal em Gym.jar"

Comment: Como você gerou esse jar?

Comment: Pela opção exportar do eclipse, depois gerar JAR file e por fim escolho o arquivo que contem o método main.

Comment: O seu erro é de que não tem classe principal no Manifest do seu JAR. Isso só pode ser porque o Eclipse não encontrou uma classe principal (uma classe com um método main) no seu projeto. Certifique-se de que está tudo certo com seu projeto. Além disso, tente abrir o seu JAR com o 7-zip ou similar, abra seu arquivo Manifest e coloque o conteúdo dele na pergunta.

Comment: O código está escrito de forma correta, possui um método main, e no eclipse ele roda normal sem problema. Abri no WinRAR o no arquivo MANIFEST.MF só tem, Manifest-Version: 1.0 e Sealed: true, isso é tudo o que tem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente, na hora de criar o arquivo, a opção "Launch Configuration" está selecionada a classe errada...

[image: imagem de export do eclipse]

Comment: Cara, que vacilo meu, era isso mesmo. Agora está funcionando normal.
Nunca teria pensando nisso.
Obrigado.